# C# web api get request fails or adds extra info

Tags: c#, webapi

I run into the problem. I have these classes.

```
public class VariantColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> productVariants { get; set; }
}

public class VariantSize
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> productVariants { get; set; }
    }
```

I added them into dbcontext

```
public DbSet<VariantColor> variantColors { get; set; }
public DbSet<VariantSize> variantSizes { get; set; }
```

I have this in VariantSizeRepository and it work fine.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<VariantSize>> GetAllSizes()
        {
            var sizes = await _dataContext.variantSizes.ToListAsync();

            if(sizes == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return sizes;
        }
```

But I have nearly identical call in VariantColorRepository

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<VariantColor>> GetVariantColors()
    {
        var colors =  _dataContext.variantColors.ToList();
        if (colors == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return colors;
    }
```

If I use ToList() not async version I get response with extra code

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "green"
    }
  ],
  "id": 242,
  "exception": null,
  "status": 5,
  "isCanceled": false,
  "isCompleted": true,
  "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
  "creationOptions": 0,
  "asyncState": null,
  "isFaulted": false
}
```

If I use ToListAsync() It trows Error

```
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported. Path: $.MoveNextAction.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Action' instances are not supported.
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.UnsupportedTypeConverter`1.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
```

I cant figure out the problem, I made these call same as VariiantSizes but it throws error...
What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you foirget to add await when the method is async ?, your code looks fine otherwise

Comment: No, I added async then using ToListAsync(), first time I see this error.

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<VariantColor>> GetVariantColors()
    {
        var colors =  _dataContext.variantColors.ToList();
        if (colors == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return colors;
    }
```

The return

```
IEnumerable<VariantColor>
```

not

```
Task<IEnumerable<VariantColor>>
```

as expected

change

```
var colors =  _dataContext.variantColors.ToList();
```

to
change to

```
var colors =  await  _dataContext.variantColors.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If I remove Task.  I cant use async, throws error

Comment: But now here is no extra code if i user not async version ToList()

Comment: if your method has async in it you shoud use await.

Comment: Or use the next code without **async** and **Task** **<T>**
```public Enumerable<VariantColor> GetVariantColors()
    {
        var colors =  _dataContext.variantColors.ToList();
        if (colors == null)`
        {
            return null;
        }

        return colors;
    }```